# create table- specified columns and properties

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

In KSQL I need to create a table based on a Kafka topic 'testtopic' that has messages like this

```
[
    {   "name": "bank meeting",
        "type": "request for loan",
        "num_rep": 1
    }, {
        "name": "bank meeting",
        "type": "open bank account",
        "num_rep": 1
    }, {
        "name": "bank meeting",
        "type": "order credit card",
        "num_rep": 1
    }, {
        "name": "transaction",
        "type": "cash withdrawal",
        "num_rep": 0
    }, {
        "name": "transaction",
        "type": "Receiving salary",
        "num_rep": 1
    }
]
```

what do I write in the brackets where I need to specify the topic's columns?
As I see it, it's an array with JSON elements.

```
CREATE table test (
    
    ????
        
    
  ) with ( kafka_topic='testtopic',value_format='???');
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM arr_test (payload ARRAY<STRUCT<name VARCHAR, type VARCHAR, num_rep INT>>) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='arr_test', PARTITIONS=2, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');


 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------

ksql> describe arr_test;

Name                 : ARR_TEST
 Field   | Type
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PAYLOAD | ARRAY<STRUCT<NAME VARCHAR(STRING), TYPE VARCHAR(STRING), NUM_REP INTEGER>>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
For runtime statistics and query details run: DESCRIBE <Stream,Table> EXTENDED;

ksql> INSERT INTO arr_test (payload) VALUES (ARRAY[STRUCT(name := 'bank meeting', type := 'request for loan', num_rep := 1)]);

ksql> select * from arr_test;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|PAYLOAD                                                                                                                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{NAME=bank meeting, TYPE=request for loan, NUM_REP=1}]                                                                                                      |
Query Completed
Query terminated
```

You can do the same for CREATE TABLE however, you will need to specify a PRIMARY KEY

You can also refer to this documentation for dealing with additional structured data types - https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/query-structured-data/